# How to iterate JSON content using jq in bash

Tags: bash, jq

I have a json content as below,

```
{
"Id": "Role1",
"Result": [
    {
        "Sub1": 1,
        "Sub2": 1,
        "StrSub": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "Sub1": 2,
        "Sub2": 1,
        "StrSub": "CDE"
    } ],
"Other": "NA"
}
```

I am trying to print as below,

```
Id
Result
Others
```

I could get the length by using `jq length t1.json`, but with the length I try to iterate the json file using `--arg index 0` within a for loop, it doesn't work (`jq --arg id 0 '.[$id]' t1.json`)

Comment: This isn't valid JSON to begin with: the array is not closed and there's a missing comma. You might be looking for `keys`, though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input has been rectified:

```
$ jq -r 'keys_unsorted[]' t1.json
Id
Result
Other
```

The reason `jq --arg id 0 '.[$id]' t1.json` does not work is that you've specified `$id` to be a JSON string.

The simplest way to pass in an integer argument is to use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`.  One of many alternatives would be to use `$id|tonumber` instead of `$id`.

Answer (score 1):

there's also an easy way to do it using a walk-path unix utility **[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc/blob/master/User%20Guide.md)**:

```
bash $ <t1.json jtc -w'[:]<>k' 
"Id"
"Other"
"Result"
bash $
```

add `-qq` if you like to drop the quotes

PS> Disclosure: I'm the creator of the `jtc` - shell cli tool for JSON operations